# How to filter/subset a data table based on condition on other columns in R?

Tags: r, filter, data.table, subset

I have a data set, similar to the example:

`Data <- data.table(Date=c("2020-01-02", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-04", "2020-01-04"), ID=c(1,2,1,1,1,1,2), Value=c(150,120,111,189,654,333,213))`

Output:

```
         Date ID Value
1: 2020-01-02  1   150
2: 2020-01-02  2   120
3: 2020-01-03  1   111
4: 2020-01-04  1   189
5: 2020-01-04  1   654
6: 2020-01-04  1   333
7: 2020-01-04  2   213
```

I would like to filter or subset `Data` by `Date` and `ID`.
For example,
If in a day, I have less than 2 observation of `ID`, then remove the `ID` and `Value` in that day.
`2020-01-02` I have only one `ID` `1`, so, this row will be removed.

I would appreciate if you could give me some advice.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just group by Date and ID, count observations and filter when there are greater than one:

```r
Data[, n:=.N, by = .(Date, ID)][n>1]
#          Date ID Value n
# 1: 2020-01-04  1   189 3
# 2: 2020-01-04  1   654 3
# 3: 2020-01-04  1   333 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, you can try:

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>% group_by(ID, Date) %>% filter(n() >= 2) %>% ungroup()
```

Output:

```
# Date          ID Value
# <chr>      <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 2020-01-04     1   189
# 2 2020-01-04     1   654
# 3 2020-01-04     1   333
```